# Может ли программа понять, что ее config был отредактирован и сменить свое поведение без перезапуска?

Tags: c#, .net, config

Например, имеется программа с каким-то app.config, где храниться путь для закачки файлов.

Может ли программа понять, когда запущена, что config был отредактирован и на основании этого выполнять закачку в другую папку?

Comment: если данные в пропрти отличаются, то конфиг менялся и делаешь все. что хочешь.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, это понятно. Получается, что нужно по таймеру чекать конфигурацию или можно как-то иначе сделать?

Comment: Используйте API-функцию `ReadDirectoryChanges` или её аналог в .Net.

Comment: @iluxa1810 да. либо в отдельном потоке читать. либо ReadDirectoryChanges юзать, как сказали выше

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, может.

Сначала надо явно загрузить свой файл настроек:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
```

Дальше надо получить список файлов, из которых этот файл настроек был собран:

```
var files = config.Locations.Cast<ConfigurationLocation>().Select(loc => loc.Path);
```

Теперь можно начать наблюдение за этими файлами:

```
var monitor = new HostFileChangeMonitor(files.ToArray());
monitor.NotifyOnChanged(_ => {
  // ...
});
```

Когда поступит сигнал об изменении файлов - надо выждать 100-200 миллисекунд и сделать все с начала.

Comment: А чем `HostFileChangeMonitor` лучше, чем традиционный `FileSystemWatcher`?

Comment: @VladD просто намного проще в использовании. При использовании FileSystemWatcher надо сгруппировать файлы по директориям - а HostFileChangeMonitor это делает внутри. Опять-таки, при использовании FileSystemWatcher очень легко поддаться соблазну мониторить постоянный список файлов - а он на самом деле же переменный (см. атрибут configSource)! HostFileChangeMonitor такой ошибки допустить не дает из-за своей "одноразовости".

Comment: Спасибо, не знал.